# mysql request every week since last 6 months

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, date

I'm trying to request my database to get numbers of rows where a specific login appears from last 6 months ordered by weeks.

The output has to be something like this :

[image]

My request is like this :

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM table1 where (`EndDate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) and CURDATE()) AND the_login LIKE 'LOGIN 1';
```

It shows every rows from last 6 month for now.
Could you complete my request or change it if needed please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `YEAR()` and `WEEK()` to extract them from the date, and group by them .

Note that I didn't use only `WEEK` because its not enough, if you'll perform this before June, weeks can be misunderstood.

Also, don't use `LIKE` for exact match, use them only for partially comparison.

```
SELECT YEAR(t.endDate) as m_Year, WEEK(t.endDate) as m_Week, count(*)
FROM table1 t
where t.`EndDate` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) 
                      and CURDATE())
  AND t.the_login = 'LOGIN 1'
GROUP BY m_Year,m_Week
```

Comment: @R.co remember to mark as an answer so other can easily see it

Comment: Yeah I know, I just had to wait 2 minutes for that ^_^